# Connect an etherent device to network via wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a old 'smart' TV which has an Ethernet port on the back, for internet usage. The issue is that we have just moved house and the closest Ethernet port is across one of the main hallways. There is also an existing power-line setup in the house for a sound system, so that rules out power-line.

What I think is needed is some kind of wifi repeater (since they normally have an Ethernet port, although I would prefer not to use one since I don't want another wifi network and they can have issues disabling the wifi), or some kind of adaptor to receive the wifi signal and output an Ethernet cable.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of boxes that do exactly what you're looking for. Just search for "Ethernet to Wi-Fi adapter" and go from there.

By the way, the powerline setup for the audio system doesn't necessarily rule out powerline networking for the TV. Although powerline Ethernet adapters are typically sold in pairs, the standards they use (such as HomePlug AV2) allow for multi-way networking, not just 2-way. On the other hand, if your powerline audio solution isn't HomePlug or one of the other well-known multi-way networking-over-powerline technologies, and is instead some audio-only thing that uses the same frequencies that HomePlug or G.Hn uses, then you're right, using powerline Ethernet adapters for your TV might interfere with that.